# Why isn't this Jquery Ajax working in Opera and Safari?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This code works in FF, Chrome, IE6/8 but not in Safari and Opera.
Any ideas why?

Here is the code:

```
var name = $('#esm').val();
        var email = $('#nam').val();
        var message = $('#med').val();
        var ad_id = $('#i_d').val();

    var data_string = 'esm='+ name + '&nam=' + email + '&med=' + message + '&i_d=' + ad_id;

            $.ajax({
                type:       "POST",
                url:        "/my_php_file.php",
                data:       data_string,
                success:    function(data) {
                    $('#tip_loader').hide();
               if(data==1){alert('success'); }
               else {alert('error'); }
                       }//end success function
        }) //end ajax call
```

I have located the error to exactly the "Ajax" call, because when I put an alertbox just before the `$.ajax` the alert shows up correctly.
However, if I put the alertbox in the success function, nothing shows up, no alert.

This only happens in Opera and Safari...

EDIT:

FYI: I include this javascript file into a php file, and I also include the jquery.js file into the php file. So this is all in an external file.

EDIT:

/main.php
/bin/jquery.js
/bin/tip.js
/bin/tip.php

I include the above js files into main.php, and the form action in main.php is set to /bin/tip.php

And the path to the ajax url is /bin/tip.php instead of my_php_file.php

Comment: I am not too good with Firebug, how should I read what it says? Also, isn't firebug for FF only, so how can I tell whats wrong in Opera?

Comment: "Net" tab, there you'll find your requests with responses.

Comment: What should I be looking for, it says "200 OK" and a load of other stuff. All seems ok. Response is what I expected.

Comment: @Camran - Opera has a debugging tool built in called Dragonfly. Go to the Tools menu -> Advanced ->Opera Dragonfly  If you don't have the File menu bar, click Menu -> Page -> Developer Tools -> Open Opera Dragonfly

Comment: @Drackir: Found it! Now I am guessing I should be looking under "Network" right? But it is blank, nothing happens when I submit... Any other tips how to troubleshoot? Thanks alot

Comment: @Camran - See my answer below. :)

Comment: Check the debugger script error console for any errors. Set breakpoints before the call to $.ajax().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opera has a debugging tool built in called Dragonfly. Go to the Tools menu -> Advanced ->Opera Dragonfly
If you don't have the File menu bar, click Menu -> Page -> Developer Tools -> Open Opera Dragonfly

Once you have it open (open it on the page that you're working on), click the Scripts tab (it'll probably ask you to refresh the page, do that) and drop down to your external js file.
Once you've found your code, you can set a breakpoint on the `$.ajax()` line by clicking on the line number on the left side. Now, trigger your code and you'll see that it will break on that JavaScript line. You can then use the inspection tab (bottom, middle) to ensure that all of your variables are set correctly. You can also step through and debug the JavaScript.

The other thing you'll want to do is add an error function like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/my_php_file.php",
    data: data_string,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#tip_loader').hide();
        if (data == 1) { alert('success'); }
        else { alert('error'); }
    }, //end success function
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});  //end ajax call
```

See if that gives you any more information.

Also, check the error console as @Mufasa suggested. It can be found under the Error Console tab in Dragonfly.

Comment: Ok, I get an errorThrown message: "ReferenceError: Security violation"... Any ideas?

Comment: @Camran - That's usually related to a cross-domain request. Is the code above exactly what you're using? Also, did you check the Error Console?

Comment: The code above is exactly what I use, also, the error console reports some CSS errors, but since I have conditional comments, it might be due to that. But no errors related to other things than css... So could the cause of this be the php file?

Comment: @Camran - I don't think so. Is the JavaScript file loading from the same server as the `/my_php_file.php` file?

Comment: Oh, the actual name of the php file is tip.php, and it is loaded all on the same server yes. Only thing is that the page where I include the javascript files is in root, and the js files are located one folder down, at the same place as the php file, check my edit to clarify this.

Comment: @Camran - I'm confused as to your folder structure. I think Opera may be thinking that you're trying to get the file from a different server. Can you set a break point on the error code and see (from the Inspection tab) what `textStatus` and `errorThrown` are?

Comment: @Camran, it's worth noting that `http://www.example.com/` and `http://example.com` (and, of course any subdomains (as an example: `http://images.example.com/`) are all considered by JavaScript to be separate domains.

Comment: I have tried breakpoints now, and the variables are actually sent correctly, however, I am having trouble checking the textStatus, I don't see that variable at all in the inspection tab.

Comment: @Camran - Does `xhr.status` give you anything? Also, did you see @David Thomas' note above?

Comment: @Drackir: I removed the path to the php file in the ajax "URL" and then added it again, exactly the same as it was, and now it works... Very Very Very strange to me, because I didn't do anything else.

Comment: @Camran - What's weird is that it didn't work in the first place! Haha. Glad you got it to work. :)

Answer (score 1):

In Opera, by default Allow File XMLHttpRequest is false. So you need to change the settings. Open Opera browser, type about:config. It will take you to the Preference screen. Go to User Prefs folder, you can see a settings Allow File XMLHttpRequest. Check that and then Save. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a way to tell.  You didn't post the php file.  Without knowing the output, we can't determine how the browser will respond.

Other tips though, #1 you are not using encodeURIComponent for any of the values being passed it.  Its much more simple to get jQuery to do it for you,

instead of data: data_string, you should have

data: { esm: name, nam: email, med: message, "i_d": ad_id }

jQuery will create the query string for you and correctly.